# How to deploy an Ubuntu touch application for other GNU/Linux distributions?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

My situation:

- I have created an Ubuntu touch application using Ubuntu SDK, in QML & C++.
- The application uses **Ubuntu UI Toolkit**
  (Ubuntu.Components 0.1)
- I want the application to run in other GNU/Linux distributions as well.

How to deploy this application along with Ubuntu Components, so that it runs on other GNU/Linux distributions as well?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to statically link to all of Qt5?  I would imagine that most modern Linuxes already have it in their repositories.  It may just be that all you need to do is include Ubuntu.Components in your binary.

If I were doing this, I'd just copy the Ubuntu.Components source into my project directory, as if it were another module.  I've never actually tried this, so you may have to play around with import paths to make sure the right version gets loaded.

I suspect that there's a more elegant way to accomplish this, but I don't have much experience producing statically linked binaries.  But maybe this will work for you until someone comes by with the real answer.

Comment: Depending on the license and distribution method of the application, it may not be feasible/legal to pull in Ubuntu.Components in that way.

Comment: Please update the answer if you can. I changed the question